# Select objects from different models and union them rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to activerecord models
`Model1 and Model2`

`Model1` has `name` and `info` fields

`Model2` has `state` and `price`

I want to make an array of objects which will be a union of model1 + model2.
Each `sum_model` object should have `name, info, state, price` properties.

It should be the sum of `Model1.all` and `Model2.all`. For example:

If `Model1.all` returns one record with `name="name" and info ="zz"`

`Model2.all` returns one record with `state='state' and price=14`

`model_sum`  should be an array of 2 objects:

```
[{name:'name', info: 'zz', state: '', price: ''}, {name:'', info: '', state: 'state', price: 14}]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are both `Model1` and `Model2` related ?

Comment: @bitsapien nope

Comment: You're probably going to need a join table to associate those two models.

Comment: I have a hard time believing this is the best way to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want to achieve by building the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) (combine every record of one table with every table of another table) between `Model1` and `Model2` and then get the attributes of the resulting model (which will have the attributes of `Model1` and `Model2` combined:

```
Model1
  .joins("CROSS JOIN #{Model2.table_name}")
  .select("#{Model1.table_name}.*, #{Model2.table_name}.*")
  .map(&:attributes)
```

No association needs to exist between the two models in order to do that.

---

**Edit after rereading the question and noticing that I missed the point**

You will first have to adjust the selects of both models in order to get the `UNION` to match columns. Luckily, one can add arbitrary selects into the AR statement, so e.g.

```
m1 = Model1.select(:name, :info, "'' as state", "'' as price")
m2 = Model2.select(:state, :price, "'' as name", "'' as info")
```

Then you will have to handcraft the UNION as this is not supported by AR. It is by Arel but I most of the time doubt that Arel is worth the struggle:

```
union = Model1.connection.unprepared_statement do
  "((#{m1.to_sql}) UNION (#{m2.to_sql})) AS unioned"
end
```

And after that you can fire away the select using the union as the from value and then call the `attributes` method of each returned entry to achieve the result you specified:

```
Model1
  .select('*')
  .from(union)
  .map(&:attributes)
```

Comment: Reread the question and noticed that I missed the point. I wrongfully assumed that the OP used the word 'union' when the cartesian product was meant and only noticed my mistake after taking a look at the specified result.